# Show that if $n$ and $k$ are integers with $1 ≤ k ≤ n$, then ${n\choose k} \le (n^k)/ 2^{k−1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I've looked everywhere but I've been unable to come up with a way to show that if $n$ and $k$ are both integers such that $1 ≤ k ≤ n$, then:

$${n \choose k} \le \frac{n^k}{2^{k−1}}$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$ 
\cfrac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot\ldots \cdot(n-k+1)}{2\cdot\ldots\cdot k} = n \cdot \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac {n-j} {j+1} \leq n \cdot \left( \cfrac n 2 \right)^{k-1}  $$

Answer (score 1):

The case $k=1$ is easy. Now suppose that for a given $n$, the result holds for all $k$. We show that the result holds at $n+1$

The "Pascal" identity
$$\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$$
can be proved by direct calculation, or by giving a combinatorial interpretation.

So we have by the induction hypothesis that 
$$\binom{n}{k}\le \frac{n^k}{2^{k-1}}+\frac{n^{k-1}}{2^{k-2}}.$$
Bring to a common denominator $2^{k-1}$. the numerator is then $n^k +2n^{k-1}$.

But by the Binomial Theorem, if $k \ge 2$ then $(n+1)^k \gt n^k+2n^{k-1}$, and we are finished.

Comment: Whats the case for k=1?

Comment: In the answer, I mentioned it is easy. For if $k=1$, then $\binom{n}{k}=n$. Also, if $k=1$ then $\frac{n^k}{2^{k-1}}=\frac{n}{1}=n$. So at $k=1$ we have equality.

Comment: Do we need to prove that further?

Comment: Well, if you want to be complete, the calculation I did just above should be mentioned.  Note that the other answers are from the point of intuition better than the one I gave.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{k} = \dfrac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdots(n-(k-1))}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots3\cdot2} \le \dfrac{n^k}{2^{k-1}}
\end{equation}